# logstash multiple output doesn't work if one of outputs fails

Tags: logstash

I have the next configuration of logstash :

```
output {  
    elasticsearch {host => "elastichost"
    stdout {codec => json}

    file {
    path => "./out.txt"
  }
```

And in case when Elasticsearch host is unavaliable then I do not receive any output at all. There is just errors about ElasticSearch output fails.

So the question is how I can configure logstash for reliable sending logs to outputs even if one of them fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Logstash 1; any output thread that blocks will hang them all up.

The design of Logstash 2 is supposed to fix this.